# How come standard functions like abs or count work on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I realized that for some standard python functions like `round` or `abs`, instead of invoking them as a method on a dataframe like:

```
df['MyCol'].round()
df['MyCol'].abs()
```

or using apply like:

```
df['MyCol'].apply(round)
df['MyCol'].apply(abs)
```

I can also call their std library equivalent directly for the same result:

```
round(df['MyCol'])
abs(df['MyCol'])
```

How come this works? Is there something in the `round` and `abs` implementations that allows to extend them to new types somehow?

Comment: Oh i did not know that as a thing i am guessing that the series type from pandas has the same dunder method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Python built-in functions are designed to be extended by classes, so they'll call a dunder method if it exists.

From the documentation of [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

> For a general Python object `number`, `round` delegates to `number.__round__`.

So when you call `round(df['MyCol'])` it's equivalent to

```
df['MyCol'].__round__()
```

Comment: My guess was correct yay

Comment: Makes sense, guess I could have read the docs :')... but anyways my test was conclusive: the humans of stackoverflow are still vastly superior to ChatGPT! <3